# how to get split commands output to file

Tags: linux, dd, stdout, split, stderr

I want to print output of below command to file, can you help me I tried 2>&1 even 2>> also

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1000 status=progress |split -b 10 -a 10
```

I have other dd command that works for me like below

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/sl/workspace/test bs=1024 count=2097152 status=progress  2>&1 | awk 'NR==4'
```

I basically wants to create 100-1000 files and want to test file creation speed on hard disk, so I preferred dd command,

can you please guide what needs to be done for above request, or else any alternate way to create 100-1000 files and want to test file creation speed on hard disk

Regards
SAMURAI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1000 status=progress 2> speed.test |split -b 10 -a 10

$ cat speed.test
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1000 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.00176463 s, 567 kB/s
```

There's nothing wrong with your command. You just need to look for the created files as in xaa, etc. in the current directory.

You could refine the output filenames by means of the prefix nd suffix options. See man split for more details.

Comment: i want to store output of dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1000 status=progress |split -b 10 -a 10  to some file, like >> test.txt 

It gives me 
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1000 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.00325396 s, 307 kB/s 

I want to paste that in some log or text file

Comment: Then just redirect the stderr of ed to a file. See my edited answer.